# Модификация вывода View в Django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте!

Встретился с Django, необходимо дополнить модуль flatpages.  Т.е. задача сводится к реализации некоторого функционала поверх для работы с контентом. Эта часть сделана успешно, код интегрирован в модель и вьюшки модуля flatpages.

Но, данный модуль необходимо затем иметь возможность перенести в другой проект. Как можно, или даже нужно, правильно сделать модификаци, чтобы иметь возможность перенесить новый модуль с проекта на проект, не поддвергая модификации старый?

Архитектурно, думаю, все можно было бы сделать в middleware, но там тоже есть свои грабли. Можно было бы сделать свой модуль, но, видимо, по причине неграмотности в Django, не могу перенаправить админку на свой модуль. А это нужно, так как модифицируется и модель, которая вдальнейшем используется и в админской вьюшке.

Подскажите пожалуйста.

**UPD**

Взять хотябы простейший пример:

```
class ExtendedFlatPage(FlatPage):
     teaser = CharField(max_length=150)

class ExtendedFlatPageForm(FlatpageForm):
     teaser = CharField(max_length=150)
     class Meta:
        model = ExtendedFlatPage

class ExtendedFlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    form = ExtendedFlatPageForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('url', 'title', 'teaser', 'content', 'sites',)}),
    )

admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(ExtendedFlatPage, ExtendedFlatPageAdmin)
```

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы он заработал в Админке?

Comment: У меня приведенный вами код работает. В админке:

![](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-DBe2ph5RkK4/T7OR-sCmGNI/AAAAAAAAG-E/yj01eTnNYqE/s400/1337168373143.png)

Comment: Решил по-своему, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По причине неграмотности? Ну так повышайте грамотность, в чем проблема?

По вашей проблеме - сделайте отдельное приложение, модифицировав в flatpages что вам нужно (не обязательно даже переделывать полностью, можно заюзать и наследование). Приложения-то по определению переносимы.

Буквально недавно у нас на проекте возникла подобная задача. Модифицируем модели, вьюхи, регистрируем в админке по аналогии с тем как это сделано в оригинале - но в `settings.py` в `INSTALLED_APPS` вместо `flatpages` (ну и в `middleware`, соответсвенно) указываем свое приложение.

Модификация исходного кода пакетов вообще-то не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: Скиньте куда-нибудь свой код, посмотрим

Comment: Я не работаю с кодом, который можно куда-то скидывать. Если наследоваться от flatpages то случается следующая ошибка:

> fp_my.fp_my: 'flatpage_ptr' has a relation with model <class 
> 'django.contrib.flatpages.models.FlatPage'>, which has either not been 
> installed or is abstract.

Comment: > Я не работаю с кодом, который можно куда-то скидывать

Тогда продолжайте пытаться. Я не думаю, что в расширении `flatpages` может быть хоть что-то секретное.

Comment: Проблема ведь не во flatpages. А в идее, которую преследует их расширение.

У вас есть какой-то подробный пример, как сделать это? По-прежнему ничего не получается.

Comment: Если бы оно все работало, я бы не спрашивал. А так, там нету примеров с модификацией view. 

Мните себя экспертом, а толку? Бесполезный треп разводить на пустом месте... поздравляю, в этом, вы эксперт.

Comment: Я не мню себя экспертом. И уж тем более не мню телепатом. Не вижу кода - не могу помочь.

Comment: @neoascetic, добавил немного кода в вопрос.